# How to execute a console command in a Java application?

Tags: java, console

I am developing a Java application which will execute a console command. What the command actually does is, it will make changes to a file, then will save a copy of it with a different name to a different folder (both of the file and the output folder is specified by the user). And it requires some binary program to do this, which is a local resource of my application.

So my code is something like:

```
...
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  File selectedFile = jFileChooser1.getSelectedFile();
  File pathAssigned = jFileChooser2.getSelectedFile();

  String file = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
  String output = pathAssigned.getAbsolutePath();
  String name = selectedFile.getName();

  // What's next???
}
```

And the usage/syntax of the command is something like:

```
"command -options /package/binary.bin "+file+" "+output+"\\"+name+"-changed"
```

So my question would now be; What will be my next code? Should I use a `Runtime`? If so, then how?

And about including a local resource path to a command, does my syntax is correct?

I am still a newbie here as well as in Java programming so please be kind to your answers/comments. Thanks!

PS. The command is a platform independent by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope the code below can help you. First you have a shell script that takes parameters.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hola"
echo "First arg: $1"
echo "Second arg: $2"
```

You save it in e.g. `/home/dac/proj/javatest2016/src/main/java/myshellScript.sh` and then you can pass the parameters from your Java code.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/home/dac/proj/javatest2016/src/main/java/myshellScript.sh", "myArg1", "myArg2");
            pb.directory(new File("/home/dac/proj/javatest2016/src/main/java"));
            Process p = pb.start();
            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }
            System.out.println("### " + output);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Test

```
### hola
First arg: myArg1
Second arg: myArg2
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much sir! I tried the code, first I make a simple Test.java that prints "Hello World" and a Batch file (I'm working on Windows) to compile it `javac %1`, then I got it successful so thank you! I'll try it on my application. +1 it is very useful :)